# save image buffer as bitmap image

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a image buffer stored as a linear array[640*480] of unsigned integer type, and I want to save this array as a bitmap image which can be viewed. I have captured an image from my camera and retrieved its image buffer from a GigE cable using in c++ code. So please tell me how to write an integer array of RGB values to Bitmap in C++ along with the header files required. I have stream buffer as

```
if (Result.Succeeded())
            {
                // Grabbing was successful, process image
                cout << "Image #" << n << " acquired!" << endl;
                cout << "Size: " << Result.GetSizeX() << " x "
                << Result.GetSizeY() << endl;

                // Get the pointer to the image buffer
            const unsigned int *pImageBuffer = (int *) Result.Buffer();
```

the pImagebuffer is the image Buffer and please ignore the Functions as they belong to a custom compiler. I just want to convert the RGB values to bitmap image **and then save it**
also the pImageBuffer is giving me the R=G=B as photo is mono chrome.

Comment: How many bits per pixel are there (32, 16, 24)? How is the `unsigned integer` representing the colors?

Comment: A small comment: Capital letter spelling of methods is C#-specific, rather than C++.

Comment: mono8 data ie. 8 bits per pixel

Answer (score -1):

Save the pixel data together with a simple BMP-file header, appropriately initialized. See the format description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).